# Android Samsung Galaxy Camera

Tags: android, camera, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I am trying to capture images using following:

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);

I am able to capture everything but there is no way to get back to my application after I am done. On the capture screen, there is just home soft key button and bottom navigation bar isn't there too. How do I get back to my activity?

Interesting thing is when I use:

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), I see the back button on invoked camera app.

Is there an extra flag parameter to enable bottom navigation bar or get the back soft key button on external camera app?

Thank you
Arvind

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity).